# spinner show data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I wanna use spinner (which show data from database) can return String to me 
from this case it work

```
spinner_InputLanguage = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_InputLanguage);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter
      = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.language, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      spinner_InputLanguage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_InputLanguage);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spinner_InputLanguage.setAdapter(adapter);

    String language = (String)spinner_InputLanguage
                .getItemAtPosition((int) spinner_InputLanguage
                        .getSelectedItemId());
```

So I try to do it by myself but it forceclose

```
cursor = db.getLang();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    SimpleCursorAdapter qc = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            cursor,
            new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_LANG},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        qc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    String language = (String)Language_Spinner.getItemAtPosition((int) Language_Spinner.getSelectedItemId());
        Language_Spinner.setAdapter(qc);
```

and this is my logcat

> 02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at com.android.proj.Sens_Create$2.onClick(Sens_Create.java:97)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   02-13 01:42:06.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this code worked for me:

```
String item = null;
Cursor cSpinner = (Cursor)(yourSpinner.getSelectedItem());
if (cSpinner != null) {
    spinnerString = cSpinner.getString(
        cc.getColumnIndex("Last_Name"));
}
```